# Ошибка GET запроса

Tags: php, javascript

Почему может возникать данная ошибка?

> GET http://192.168.0.101/get.php?get=nick undefined (undefined)

Comment: Друзья-телепаты, вопрос к вам! Чувствую, что в меню `Закрыть` и `Тревога` пора ввести пункт "Закрыто до появления телепатов на форуме" (с) "До востребования", честное слово.

Comment: Вопрос стоял что это за ошибка, а не в каком месте кода она возникла!

Comment: Все телеки извелись, нелегкая у них работа )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно что в запрос JS'om подставляется какоето значение, вот там где сейчас `undefined` это значение какой-то переменной, т.е. надо найти какая переменная не определена и поправить :)
PS:undefined тип данных JavaScript, слово undefined переводится как неопределнность

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите [тут](http://translate.google.com/#en|ru|undefined), может поможет :)